# Conditionally including content into Django 1.2 templates

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I include with Django what Symfony calls 'components' - bits of logic and a template that's not associated with the content of the current page?

For example I want to include a sidebar that displays a list of the top 10 articles on the site. It should always be displayed if the user is looking at either an 'article' page or a 'video' page. Also, the top 10 articles component needs its own CSS and JS as well as producing content.

If I have a base template that contains sections for "content", "css" and "js", and 'article' and 'video' templates that extend the base template and then define "sidebar" blocks inside "content", what's the 'Django' way of going about this?

Thanks

Comment: where does "conditional include" stands in your example?

Comment: because the top 10 articles sidebar element should only appear on the 'article' or 'video' section pages, not across the whole site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom tags are what you want - specifically, [inclusion tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) that let you render another template within the current one.

Comment: That looks great. Thanks. Will it let me append to the base template's "css" and "js" blocks though?

Comment: There's a built-in include tag already: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: yes, but include includes the whole template - it won't let me append to blocks in the parent template

Comment: So I think if I use a custom tag to update context variables I could put my CSS, JS and content where I want

Comment: ... like described here: http://slavus.net/article/django-formmediacontext/ - in the third box down.